# Creating Subset data frames in R within For loop

Tags: r

What I am trying to do is filter a larger data frame into 78 unique data frames based on the value of the first column in the larger data frame. The only way I can think of doing it properly is by applying the `filter()` function inside a `for()` loop:

```
 for (i in 1:nrow(plantline)) 
            {x1 = filter(rawdta.df, Plant_Line == plantline$Plant_Line[i])}
```

The issue is I don't know how to create a new data frame, say x2, x3, x4... every time the loop runs.

Can someone tell me if that is possible or if I should be trying to do this some other way?

Comment: Can you show us an example of `plantline` please?

Answer (score 2):

There must be many duplicates for this question

```
split(plantline, plantline$Plant_Line)
```

will create a list of data.frames.

However, depending on your use case, splitting the large data.frame into pieces might not be necessary as grouping can be used.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `split` -

```
# creates a list of dataframes into 78 unique data frames based on
# the value of the first column in the larger data frame
lst = split(large_data_frame, large_data_frame$first_column)

# takes the dataframes out of the list into the global environment
# although it is not suggested since it is difficult to work with 78 
# dataframes
list2env(lst, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

The names of the dataframes will be the same as the value of the variables in the first column.

Comment: Why take the data frames out of the list? Just makes them harder to work with.

Comment: I agree, but that is what OP's `for` loop would have done - added the dataframes to the global environment. I also added it for completeness, in case at a later point someone looks up this question, and the number of unique values in the splitting column is much lower, say 3 or 4.

Comment: I'd recommend at least *mentioning* the alternative rather than helping newbies shoot themselves in the foot because that's what they're trying to do.

Comment: @Gregor, understood. Thank you. Does the edit make it better?

Comment: Much improved. To anyone reading this - it's easy to use a `for` loop or `lapply` (or `Map` or many other options... see the `purrr` package) to work on each data frame in a `list`. However it is harder and bug-prone` to use `paste` and `assign` and `get` and other hacks to work with a bunch of nearly-identical data frames in your environment. I'd strongly recommend keeping them in a nice list.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if we could see the dataframes....

I propose something nevertheless. You can create a list of dataframes:

```
dataframes <- vector("list", nrow(plantline))
for (i in 1:nrow(plantline)){ 
     dataframes[[i]] = filter(rawdta.df, Plant_Line == plantline$Plant_Line[i])
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `assign` :

```
for (i in 1:nrow(plantline)) 
        {assign(paste0(x,i), filter(rawdta.df, Plant_Line == plantline$Plant_Line[i]))}
```

alternatively you can save your results in a `list` :

```
X <- list()    
for (i in 1:nrow(plantline)) 
        {X[[i]] = filter(rawdta.df, Plant_Line == plantline$Plant_Line[i])}
```

Comment: `fortunes::fortune(236)`

*The only people who should use the assign function are those who fully understand why you should never use
the assign function.*
   -- Greg Snow
      R-help (July 2009)

Comment: I know not the best practice, but thanks for introducing me the fortunes package!

Answer (score 0):

Would be easier with sample data. by would be my favorite.

```
d <- data.frame(plantline = rep(LETTERS[1:3], 4),
                x = 1:12, 
                stringsAsFactors = F)

l <- by(d, d$plantline, data.frame)

print(l$A)
print(l$B)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using `plyr`:

```
ma <- cbind(x = 1:10, y = (-4:5)^2, z = 1:2)
ma <- as.data.frame(ma)

library(plyr)
dlply(ma, "z") # you split ma by the column named z
```